# How to pass the event target as $emit argument in VueJS2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have this VueJS 2 template

```
    var aThing = Vue.component('something',{
    template :` <button @click="$emit('custom-event','hello there')">Click me</button>`});
```

Is it possible to pass the button that was actually pushed as an argument to `$emit` ? For example in the `click` event it is usually passed but the event and can be accesed in a function like this

```
function(event){
  event.target; //I want this
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle of my issue

https://jsfiddle.net/wntzv4sk/2/

Comment: `$emit('custom-event', 'hello-there', $event.target)`.

Comment: @Bert Yeap, that seems to be it. Do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vue makes the event object available in the template via a variable called `$event`. This is [documented here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers).

That being the case, you could emit the target of the event in this manner:

```
$emit('custom-event', 'hello-there', $event.target)
```